# Advice batch-File should open origin with data

Tags: batch-file, echo, autoexec

I have never worked with batch-Files, so I´m sorry for that stupid question:

I have a batch-File containing these 2 lines of code.

```
echo def autoexec{ run C:\Users\s\Desktop\BBB\Temp\amiX_VectorPlot_GasVel#1.scr;} >%TEMP%\amix.cnf         
C:\Programme\OriginLab\Origin2015\ -c %TEMP%\amix
```

I understand that the second line opens Origin2015.  But can someone explain to me what  the part cith -c %TEMP%.... means and what the first line does?

Thank you

itelly

Comment: So i would say the first line outputs  `def autoexec{ run C:\Users\s\Desktop\BBB\Temp\amiX_VectorPlot_GasVel#1.scr;}` to a temp file (`amix.cnf`) then `Origin2015 -c %TEMP%\amix` calls the temp file and uses that as its config file does that make sense ?

Comment: Thanks Valorax, this makes sense.